# Trying to find FP,FN,TP,TN but i'm having some errors

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, confusion-matrix

I'm trying to find FP,FN,TP,TN values but it gives me this error:

```
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'sum'
```

Here is that part my code:

```
FP = confusion_matrix.sum(axis=0) - np.diag(confusion_matrix)   <-- Error in this line
FN = confusion_matrix.sum(axis=1) - np.diag(confusion_matrix)
TP = np.diag(confusion_matrix)
TN = confusion_matrix.sum() - (FP + FN + TP)

TPR = TP/(TP+FN)
TNR = TN/(TN+FP) 
PPV = TP/(TP+FP)
NPV = TN/(TN+FN)
FPR = FP/(FP+TN)
FNR = FN/(TP+FN)
FDR = FP/(TP+FP)

ACC = (TP+TN)/(TP+FP+FN+TN)
```

Comment: `confusion_matrix` is a function, you need to call it. You should include the definition of `confusion_matrix`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're getting this error because `confusion_matrix` is a function, and you're trying to call the `sum` function on it.

If you're using `confusion_matrix` from [scikit-learn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix.html), in the simple binary case you can get FP, FN, TP, & TN like this:

```
tn, fp, fn, tp = confusion_matrix([0, 1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 1, 0]).ravel()
```

Otherwise, you'll want to call it on your actual and predicted y before you calculate positives and negatives.

```
cm = confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred)
# compute FP, FN, TP, & TN here on cm
```

Comment: Well i used That But it gives me this error:

`Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [29324, 19550]`

Comment: @Mehdi In that case, your true and predicted sets don't have the same number of values. You may have mixed up your training and validation sets. Please show that part of your code.

Comment: You can unpack instead of raveling: `((tn, fp), (fn, tp))`